# How to combine 4 multidimensional arrays into 1 multidimensional

Tags: php

I unload 4 different tables from MySQL with different keys. I need to combine them into one array. I'll sort them by date (but it's not important and I know how to do it).

As I see it:

```
foreach ($rows2 as $msgs2) { 
 $arraynew = array_merge($arraynew, array('cost' => $msgs2['vivod'], 'date' => $msgs2['date'], 'type' => '1'));
}

foreach ($rows3 as $msgs3) { 
 $arraynew = array_merge($arraynew, array('cost' => $msgs3['price'], 'date' => $msgs3['data'], 'type' => '2'));
}

foreach ($rows4 as $msgs4) { 
 $arraynew = array_merge($arraynew, array('cost' => $msgs4['price'], 'date' => $msgs4['data'], 'type' => '3'));
}

foreach ($rows5 as $msgs5) { 
  $arraynew = array_merge($arraynew, array('cost' => $msgs5['cost'], 'date' => $msgs5['data'], 'type' => '4'));
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: You could use AS in your SQL to get the same field names: `SELECT vivod AS price FROM items` if that helps.

Comment: Your array_merge should work if you wrap your array in an array in the array merge.  However I wouldn't recommend using `array_merge` for adding an additional element to the end of an array, rather use: ` $array[] = $var;`.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, it's useful to say what it is doing and how that differs to what you expect it to.  Give an example of your desired outcome if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$foos = [
    ['vivod' => '11', 'date' => '20140112'],
    ['vivod' => '23', 'date' => '20140113']
];
$bars = [
    ['price' => '29', 'date' => '20171201'],
    ['price' => '31', 'date' => '20170102']
];

$result = array();

foreach ($foos as $foo) { 
    $result[] = array('cost' => $foo['vivod'], 'date' => $foo['date'], 'type' => '1');
}

foreach ($bars as $bar) { 
    $result[] = array('cost' => $bar['price'], 'date' => $bar['date'], 'type' => '2');
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'cost' => '11',
    'date' => '20140112',
    'type' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'cost' => '23',
    'date' => '20140113',
    'type' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'cost' => '29',
    'date' => '20171201',
    'type' => '2',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'cost' => '31',
    'date' => '20170102',
    'type' => '2',
  ),
)
```

Comment: $result = []; - Swears at [], crash PHP.

Comment: You must be using an older version of Php (<5.4).  Replace that line with `$result = array();`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php),

```
<?php
$ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
$ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [favorite] => Array
                (
                    [0] => red
                    [1] => green
                )

            [0] => blue
        )

    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', array())`.

Example:

```
$a = array(array(1, 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6),array(7, 8, 9),array(10, 11, 12));
$result = array_reduce($a, 'array_merge', array());`
```